# React - how to get the application environment at UI with webpack define-plugin?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am working on a React application. In there I have to showcase different functionality based on whether app is running in dev mode or production. My query is how do I get this application environment in my React code?

I tried below code but it did not work:

```
// webpack.config.js
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      appenv: JSON.stringify('dev')
    })
  ]
// any-component.js
console.log("Env: " + appenv);

//error
appenv is not defined.
```

I also tried `EnvironmentPlugin` of webpack but got same error.

Comment: You can `console.log(process.env)`

Comment: @illiteratewriter yes that logs a big object but does not include the appenv as I did not add it to that. Am I right?

Comment: `process.env` contains all the environment variables you have. So you can check `process.env.appenv` if that is the name..

Comment: @illiteratewriter it throws undefined!

Comment: Just go through the environment variables to check for the name of the variable you need

Comment: @illiteratewriter the env is an empty object.

Comment: `DefinePlugin` works well on my side. Could you post a minimum demo project, including `package.json` and other necessary files?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using create-react-app?

Following this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/865#issuecomment-252148907) they said all the key in .env file must start with `REACT_APP_` to get it to work.

ps. sorry if it's not the case, I couldn't reply a comment yet.